# HibernateSearch/Lucene searching in index with undersclore

Tags: search, lucene, indexing

I declared a field where I wanna save values with underscores in it. Therefore I marked the field with the @Field annotation like:

@Field(name = "underscoreField", index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED).

In Luke I can see that the index is created correctly. For instance:

ABC_EF_AB

When I search for "ABC_EF_AB" or "ABC_" I can't find any result. I already tried the Standard and the Keyword Analyzer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [WhitespaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html). It uses a WhitespaceTokenizer that breaks at whitespace, so it should allow underscores.